# Add UIScrollView to my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have gone through many tutorials but most of them tell how to add a `UIScrollView` using the interface builder. I need to add a scrollview using code. I went through several [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9i4NzkZHnY) and what they did was they add the `UIView` to the `UIScrollView` . `[scrollView addSubView:myView];` simple as that ad connect to using interface builder.

Can someone please guide me as in how to add a `UIScrollView` using code (Only Code)

Answer (score 1):

Is really simple:

```
UIScrollView * scroller = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGTectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:scroller];

int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    UIView * myview = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
    [scroller addSubview:myView];

    x += myView.frame.size.width;

}

[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, 480)];
```

This code was compiled in my head, so sorry if there is a sintax mistake.

Comment: I guess `self.view` is the 1st half of the scrollview and myView is the second 1/2. SO if i want to add some labels etc on the bottom half of the scrollView i need to add the labels to `myView` ?

Comment: ´self.view´ is the main view of your controller, and ´myView´ is any view you want, it could be UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView, anything, and in the ´frame´ you specify any size or position you want!

Answer (score 1):

All my examples use code rather than the nib - it's way easier to create and configure a scroll view in code! See here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/tree/master/convertedToIOS5

The scroll view examples start with p482p494scrollViewInCode.